sort multi dimension array in php
PHP
Format : $salesData["suppliers"][$supplierkey]['sales'][$salesPeriod]['sales']
I want to sort (desc):
The key $salesData["suppliers"][$supplierkey] by the numerical value populated in $salesData["suppliers"][$supplierkey]['sales'][0]['cost']
So the following example:
$salesData["suppliers"][Dong]
$salesData["suppliers"][Ding]

Would be changed to:
$salesData["suppliers"][Ding]
$salesData["suppliers"][Dong]

Because
$salesData["suppliers"][Ding][sales][0][cost] = 231.0600
$salesData["suppliers"][Dong][sales][0][cost] = 92.8900

Is it possible to do it on multidimension arrays? I assume I need to use array_multisort somehow?
Any advise would be appreciated
[
  {
    suppliers: {
      Dong: {
        ID: 3663313744756234943,
        sales: [
          { cost: 92.8900, sales: 180.869565 },
          { cost: 12.9900, sales: 394.782609 },
          {
            locations: {
              salesRow: 18,
              costRow: 19,
              GPRow: 20,
              marginRow: 21,
              pSalesChangeRow: 22,
              pGPChangeRow: 23,
              ptotalSalesRow: 24,
              ptotalGPRow: 25,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      Ding: {
        ID: 3678436471493790070,
        sales: [
          { cost: 231.0600, sales: 95.565217 },
          { cost: 26.8200, sales: 85.130435 },
          {
            locations: {
              salesRow: 28,
              costRow: 29,
              GPRow: 30,
              marginRow: 31,
              pSalesChangeRow: 32,
              pGPChangeRow: 33,
              ptotalSalesRow: 34,
              ptotalGPRow: 35,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
]

The other examples on this site show 1 level down sorting but not multi levels down.
I tried :
Foreach($salesData["suppliers"] as $supplierkey=>$id) {

        $keys = array_column($salesData["suppliers"], 'cost'); 
        
        array_multisort($keys, SORT_ASC, $new); 
        
        var_dump($new);

        die();
}

but it provides an error I don't think I am getting :'cost' right?

Yeah I was looking at that earlier but I don't 100% get it because I don't know the value of [$supplierkey] do I have to do a Foreach($salesData["suppliers"] as $supplierkey->$id) to get that to work?
$keys = array_column($salesData["suppliers"][$supplierkey], 'cost');
array_multisort($keys, SORT_DSC, $new);
var_dump($new);
Does it know to keep looking down until it finds Cost?

I tried this and got an error:
Foreach($salesData["suppliers"] as $supplierkey=>$id){
$keys = array_column($salesData["suppliers"][$supplierkey], 'cost');
array_multisort($keys, 'SORT_DSC', $new);
var_dump($new);
die();
}
: Warning: array_multisort(): Argument #2 is expected to be an array or a sort flag in /home/g/public_html/auto/index.php on line 9053

This should be easy. 1st you store all the costs in an array and then sort that costs array. Now reorder the main suppliers array based on the sorted costs array.
Something like the following:
function sortByCost($salesData)
{
    // Storing the costs
    $costs = [];
    foreach ($salesData["suppliers"] as $supplierKey => $supplierData) {
        $costs[$supplierKey] = $supplierData["sales"][0]["cost"];
    }

    // Sort the costs array
    arsort($costs);

    // Reordering the suppliers based on the sorting of cost array keys
    $sortedSuppliers = [];
    foreach ($costs as $supplierKey => $cost) {
        $sortedSuppliers[$supplierKey] = $salesData["suppliers"][$supplierKey];
    }

    $salesData["suppliers"] = $sortedSuppliers;

    return $salesData;
}


You can use uasort to define yourself the sorting condition and to keep the named keys of your array.
foreach($salesData as &$item) {
    uasort(
        $item['suppliers'],
        fn($a, $b) => $b['sales'][0]['cost'] <=> $a['sales'][0]['cost']
    );
}

demo
Note that you have to use a reference in the foreach loop (otherwise you will sort only a copy of your item and not the item itself in your array).
